# Group data by date in Splunk

Tags: splunk, group

I have data that is displayed in Splunk query as below: (data for 3 column displayed in 3 separate rows)

```
|Date    |Tier 1|Tier 2|Tier 3
|1/1/2022|33|BLANK|BLANK        
|1/1/2022|BLANK |56|BLANK   
|1/1/2022|BLANK|BLANK|121
|1/2/2022|21|BLANK|BLANK        
|1/2/2022|BLANK |78|BLANK   
|1/2/2022|BLANK|BLANK|543
```

I need to display data as follows in the table

```
|Date    |Tier 1|Tier 2|Tier 3
|1/1/2022|33|56|121
|1/2/2022|21|78|543
```

Here's a small snippet of my query

```
|eval Tier1=(StatusCode>400)
|eval Tier2=(StatusCode>499)
|eval Tier3=(StatusCode>500)
| fields Date Tier1 Tier2 Tier3
| sort Date
```

Answer (score 1):

To regroups the results, use the `stats` command.

```
| eval Tier1=(StatusCode>400)
| eval Tier2=(StatusCode>499)
| eval Tier3=(StatusCode>500)
| fields Date Tier1 Tier2 Tier3
| stats values(*) as * by Date
```

Comment: Using stats values(*) as * by Date worked. Thanks